# How to set read only to a hard drive vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have start to make an application to lock and unlock folders and files 
my question is the any method to lock or unlock a hard drive set to read only? in vb.net

i have all the code for the files and folders working but i have try to google it and i can not find any example for it, any help with it is great.

for lock the folder this is my code how can i do the same for a hard drive?
This is My Code

```
Imports System.Security.AccessControl
Imports System.IO
Public Class mainForm

Private Sub btnBrowse_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse.Click
    With FolderBrowserDialog1
        If .ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            txtLokasiDirektori.Text = .SelectedPath
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub btnKunci_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnKunci.Click
    If txtLokasiDirektori.Text <> "" Then
        Dim SatpamFile As FileSystemSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(txtLokasiDirektori.Text)
        SatpamFile.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(Environment.UserName, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny))
        File.SetAccessControl(txtLokasiDirektori.Text, SatpamFile)
        MsgBox("" & txtLokasiDirektori.Text & " Folder has been locked!")
    Else
        MsgBox("Please choose the folder!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnBuka_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBuka.Click
    If txtLokasiDirektori.Text <> "" Then
        Dim SatpamFile As FileSystemSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(txtLokasiDirektori.Text)
        SatpamFile.RemoveAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(Environment.UserName, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny))
        File.SetAccessControl(txtLokasiDirektori.Text, SatpamFile)
        MsgBox("" & txtLokasiDirektori.Text & " Folder has been opened!")
    Else
        MsgBox("Please choose the folder!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnTutup_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTutup.Click
    Dim pesan As MsgBoxResult
    pesan = MsgBox("Do you want exit?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Exit")
    If pesan = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        End
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked
    changeForm.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub LinkLabel2_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel2.LinkClicked
    Form1.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub mainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
End Class~
```

finally maybe found some example

```
Public Function GetDriveSerial() ' (xDrive As String) As String
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim Flg As Boolean
    Dim xDr As String

    On Error GoTo SKIPIT

    Flg = False

    For Each dr In FSO.Drives
        xDr = Left(dr, 1)
        If FSO.GetDrive(xDr).IsReady = True Then
            GetDriveSerial = FSO.GetDrive(xDr).SerialNumber
            MsgBox(GetDriveSerial) ' Check details below...
            If GetDriveSerial = "203462167" Then
                Flg = True : Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If Flg = True Then
        MsgBox("Welcome the world of Media Ads ...")
    Else
        MsgBox("LOCK NOT FOUND...!")
    End If

 SKIPIT:
    Exit Function

End Function
```

i have try but i get an error at the line For Each dr In FSO.Drives dr is not declared

Comment: I guess you won't get it, since the OS needs to write internal information in sectors all time. Neither in VB.NET, nor in ASM...  Anyway, should you verified if even changing the folder Access Control there isn't it vulnerable to a boot in LINUX made by USB devices?

Comment: Yes i see what you mean , i have made that on a comp of a friend to unlock his comp pass and definitely yes its vulnerable his there any way i can lock and unlock the usb ?

Comment: Sure, but only at BIOS/UEFI since the "attacker" may provide a boot to load himself into the system. Anyway, you can set/unset USB ports changing some parameters at Windows Registry and/or monitoring the USB activity - but you will need to know deeply the hardware and its interaction with Windows...

Comment: well i just found maybe a way to start

Comment: i go to edit to insert the new foud code

Comment: This code is unusefull.... It will avoid YOUR application to run, but not make the harddisk "readonly" or protected anyway.  And even different HD's may not have serial numbers.

Comment: I think this will point you in the right direction : https://superuser.com/questions/560079/make-internal-hd-read-only